# How to use java methods defined in another class/file

Tags: java, package

I've been working on some problems from Project Euler, and, in the process, have written a lot of useful methods (in Java) that I might like to use in other Java projects. I want to be able to call them in the way that you call a function from java.lang.math, so if I had a method primeFactor() I could call it using `MyMathMethods.primeFactor(number)`. How would I go about this? Would I make some kind of package that I could import? Would I make a superclass that includes all my useful math-y functions and have whatever class I'm working with in a new project extend that? There are probably multiple ways to do this, but I don't know what is best. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is in the same folder you wouldn't need to import it. If it is in a different folder, then you have to. Files are declared in a specific package at the top. For example: `package java.lang;` would be at the top of the `Object` class. So then, you can call `import java.lang.Object` to access the `Object` methods and constructors.

Answer (score 3):

Mark your utility methods as `public static.` Package your classes containing those utility methods in a jar. Add/Refer that jar in your project, where you want to use the. Then in your code you can call them in a static way lke : `MyUtilityClass.myUtilityMethod();`

Answer (score 2):

The best thing for this situation is to work in meaningful packages and make their jar
You can create a package like

```
/* File name : Animal.java */
package animals;

    interface Animal {
       public void eat();
       public void travel();
    }
```

Also on classes

```
package animals;

/* File name : MammalInt.java */
public class MammalInt implements Animal{

   public void eat(){
      System.out.println("Mammal eats");
   }

   public void travel(){
      System.out.println("Mammal travels");
   } 

   public int noOfLegs(){
      return 0;
   }

   public static void main(String args[]){
      MammalInt m = new MammalInt();
      m.eat();
      m.travel();
   }
}
```

You can import them like 
`import animals.*;` OR be more specific `import animals.MammalInt;`
**Now** you can make the jar file , import it in your project and use its method
You can eaisly do it by this command
`jar cmf MyJar.jar Manifest.txt MyPackage/*.class`

[For more details about jar creation please see this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html)
**As a side note:** Be carefull about visibility of members and functions while packaging it
Because there usage and accessibility matters a lot while we are using them

Answer (score 0):

You could create separate java project with your util classes only and then create jar file and import into any another project.

Answer (score 0):

Simply instantiate the class. Like your example, if you had a class `MyMathMethods` with the function `primeFactor(number)` then at other classes, simply instantiate it with something like `private MyMathMethods myMathMethods;`. Now, to call the function simply do `myMathMethods.primeFactor(number);` You may need to import its package as well.

Answer (score 0):

False understanding of packages is any class defined within a package is visible to all other classes. Not true from my experience.  If you have classes containing utility style methods you want to make available in another class?  Simply declare a new instance of the class in the class you need the method in.  Like...  private MathUtilsClass mathUtilsClass = new MathUtilsClass():  Then any method you want to call from this class uses the new identifier, e.g. mathUtilsClass.greatFunction();  This is stupidly easy and should solve your problem.